# Whatsapp not installing after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger

I have done factory reset on my phone Samsung (galaxy Y duos) android version 2.3.6 and after that Whats-app is not installing. Its showing your device is not compatible .
But, how can be that, when factory reset is done updates are removed totally so it must be , but it is not so.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. You have a really old Android version and modern apps won't install.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the newest version of WhatsApp I found that is compatible with Android 2.3.3+ (WhatsApp Messenger 2.16.382)

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-16-382-release/whatsapp-messenger-2-16-382-android-apk-download/

I suspect since your phone is old, you will need the x86 arch variant.